# Automatic upload of image to server without reloading page

Tags: node.js, express, webrtc

I'm creating a video chat application using WebRTC, nodejs and express js. I want to have images on my server, containing snapshots of the streams in each chat room. One image for each room.

My proposed solution is to assign a leader for each room whose mission is the get the snapshots(imagedata of each stream) and merge into one image and upload it to the server, which stores it under imgs/rooms/ and repeat this every time someone joins or leave the room or every 5 minutes.

The problem however, is to upload the image without reloading the page.

I'm thankful for any help I can get, please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).
It has the ability to talk to your webserver asynchronously, so the user doesn't have to update his page. You can get the same result using websockets, but that is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use client side file upload plugins like [Jquery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) or [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). Once these plugins are configured, you can access the file through request object on  the server.